# Show "Number stored as Text" error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using an Advanced Filter, among others, with 0 and 1's. The filter works correctly only if in the Data sheet the cells with 1 and 0 have the error message "Number stored as text" displayed. For that I have to manually open the cell with double click and press Enter. Then the error message appears and the filter works. If I don't do that, the filter doesn't work.

Alternatively I can click on the cell with 1 or 0 and press F2 to display the error message.

Is there a way with VBA that I can automatically do that?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: No need for VBA. If you want to convert numbers stored as text into numbers then you can (1) either use an Excel function to convert the value to text or a number `=Value()` or (2) you can multiply all values in that column by 1 and Excel will automatically convert all numbers stored as text into numbers. To achieve the latter of the two simply enter a 1 somewhere on the sheet, copy the 1, then select the column you want to convert and use `Paste Special` to multiply the `Values` only.

Comment: Hi Ralph, Thanks, but I don't want to convert the numbers stored as text to numbers. I want the error message to appear automatically without me having to enter the cell and pushing "Enter". I want the numbers to be stored as text and the error message to appear. It's the only way the Advanced Filter is working properly.

Comment: Change your filter to filter for numbers 1 or 0. That's easier (given my multiple choices above). If you want to abuse Excel for text then it's getting complicated and you'll have to write a VBA sub to do all that. But Excel is not meant for text but rather for numbers. So I'd go with the easy way as described.

Comment: I tried that already. The problem is, that when I take numbers I can't choose for one criteria but have to be right for all criterias for the entry to be displayed. To hit one correct criteria is not enough you have to have all of them right.

Answer (score 4):

You'll find that buried deep in the Range properties for the cells, specifically in the Errors collection. Just find the cells where that error is present, then set the `Ignore` property to `True`:

```
Public Sub IgnoreNumsAsText()
    Dim current As Range
    For Each current In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
        With current
            If .Errors.Item(xlNumberAsText).Value = True Then
                .Errors.Item(xlNumberAsText).Ignore = True
            End If
        End With
    Next current
End Sub
```