# Macro to convert every 9th column into numbers in excel

Tags: vba, excel

For some reason, even when I select a column, right click, and format the cells to be numbers, I still get an alert with a green corner in the cell that says that it's a number stored as text. I then highlight the range, click the exclamation point in the yellow box, and convert the range to numbers.

The problem is that I have to do this for hundreds of ranges.

How can I make a macro to highlight a range (e.g. XP2:XP2700) in every 9th column, and convert the entire range to numbers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show "Number stored as Text" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36157512/show-number-stored-as-text-error)

Comment: Start by using the macro recorder.  If you run into problems, post back with your code and a clear description of the problem.

Comment: The Text-to-Columns (fixed width, Finish) is the easiest way to convert whole columns of text-that-look-like-a-number into true numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a follow-up to the OP's previous question, which, I answered.

Load the data into an array typecast it into a number then write it back over the original range.

```
Sub ConvertToNumber()
    Dim x As Long, y As Long
    Dim Data

    With Worksheets("CPR Test 2013-2015")
        For y = 1 To 1582 Step 9
            Data = .Cells(2, y).Resize(2699, 1).Value
            For x = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
                If IsNumeric(Data(x, 1)) And Not IsEmpty(Data(x, 1)) Then
                    Data(x, 1) = CDbl(Data(x, 1))
                End If
            Next
            .Cells(2, y).Resize(2699, 1).Value = Data
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```