# Clear or ignore all Range.errors in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I'm trying to clear all errors (Range.Errors Property, not value errors) on a worksheet. Is it possible to do it **without** dealing with each cell **individually** ?

`.Range("C3").Errors(xlNumberAsText).Ignore = True` works fine (whether there is an error or not in C3).

But `.Range("C3:F3").Errors(xlNumberAsText).Ignore = True` or `.Cells.Errors(xlNumberAsText).Ignore = True` don't.

Looking as [MSDN Excel VBA reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/ff835287.aspx), the property should work for any Range (whether it is multi-cell or not), isn't it ?

> *expression* .Errors
>
> *expression* A variable that represents a Range object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show "Number stored as Text" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36157512/show-number-stored-as-text-error)

Comment: Maybe one could set `Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.NumberAsText = False` to ignore those errors and `Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.NumberAsText = True` to not ignore.

Comment: @Comintern, your proposed solution it to check cells individually (`For Each current In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells`). That's specifically what I'm trying not not do.

Comment: @AxelRichter, I would consider changing the `ErrorCheckingOptions` settings if I could use it on this specific worksheet, but I'm not willing to change the application settings of users (and changing it every time the user activate/deactivate the sheet seems like a bad idea).

Comment: @Tibo: No, `Application.ErrorCheckingOptions` is an application setting and not possible only for one sheet. That's why I have not posted this as an answer. But as far as I know, the `Errors` object can only be gotten cell by cell. The concept `Range` in `Excel` is a little bit confusing some times, not only in this case.